# Android Studio (adb) stopped to see my device (Mac)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have Nexus 7 tablet, and Android Studio, and I was able to see my tablet yesterday or two days before, but since yesterday or today when I connect this device, I dont see it in devices list when I want to run my application.

I tried to quit Android Studio, I tried to kill adb (ps -e | grep adb then
kill -9 pid_adb) and it seems killing of adb had an effect, because AS window when one selects the deployment target was displaying message "initializing adb", but still I dont see my device. I also tried to turn off and turn on my tablet, nothing worked.

I tried to disconnect and reconnect USB cable, I tried to restart Mac.

I also tried to turn off and turn on the Developer debugging in tablet settings.

This tablet runs Android 5.1.1. I have two more devices (Android 4.4 and Android 6) and both are visible.

I am using Mac (from my experience Mac is better to detect USB devices than Windows btw).

What could be problem that in Tablet's notifications i see that there is pending system update ready - to Android 5.1.1 - "downloaded and verified, click to restart and install" which is strange because in system info i already see 5.1.1. So if the pending installation could block the USB debugging i dont know.

Does anybody know why i stopped to see my device, what could be the problem?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably obvious but did you try:

Restarting adb using server commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Use a known good USB cable ie. one that works for the other devices as a worn cable can stop working.

Make sure when you turn developer options on (on the device) that you also turn on USB Debugging. USB debugging icon should be a persistent notification on the phone.

Comment: Hi, when i type adb in console i get -bash: adb: command not found, that's why used the method using process list, i can try your way but i guess it is similar. It is still same cable, but i can try another. I know that sometimes the cable can be the reason. Yes usb debugging should be enabled, i tried it turn it off and on. You are right that the (lollipop) debugging icon is not displayed if i remember good (now is tablet updating). But the battery icon was notifying power source connected. I will see after update.

Comment: Hmm strange now after the update finished, when i connect the cable i immediatlly see the lollipop debugging icon and now it works. What is strange it still displays the update notifications (it says due low battery), although it was updating. So probably it was some tablet problem

Comment: I use multiple USB-connected Android devices that are generally recognized by ADB, however can attest to ADB consistently stopping to recognize the devices after some time. This happens frequently and causes significant loss in productivity. If you experience similar problems and want Google to prioritize fixing this issue, please consider up-voting this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=329303.